# What’s the equivalence of \ExecuteOptions when kvoptions is used?

Tags: kvoptions

Consider the following short `.sty` package:

```
%% This is file `mypackage.sty'
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1997/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}
\DeclareOption{myoptionone}{Do something}
\DeclareOption{myoptiontwo}{Do some other things}
\DeclareOption{myoptionthree}{Do something awesome}
\ExecuteOptions{myoptionone,myoptiontwo}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\endinput
```

When loaded using `\usepackage{mypackage}`, the options `myoptionone` and `myoptiontwo` are executed as default.

Now, I want to add a key value option `foo=<value>` to `mypackage.sty` using the [`kvoptions`](https://ctan.org/pkg/kvoptions) package, with the following default settings: `foo=bar` and maintaining the original `myoptionone` and `myoptiontwo`.

So far, I got

```
%% This is file `mypackage.sty'
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1997/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{
  family=hmm,
  prefix=hmm@
}
\DeclareVoidOption{myoptionone}{Do something}
\DeclareVoidOption{myoptiontwo}{Do some other things}
\DeclareVoidOption{myoptionthree}{Do something awesome}
\DeclareStringOption[bar]{foo}[bar]
%\ExecuteOptions{myoptionone,myoptiontwo}% This doesn't work.
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
\endinput
```

What’s the equivalence of `\ExecuteOptions` when `kvoptions` is used? I don’t think I understand [this discussion on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/MQ0hu33Kr7M).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package `kvoptions` is based on `keyval`, which provides `\setkeys`. You have to pass the name of the family and the options:

```
%% This is file `mypackage.sty'
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1997/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{
  family=hmm,
  prefix=hmm@
}
\DeclareVoidOption{myoptionone}{Do something}
\DeclareVoidOption{myoptiontwo}{Do some other things}
\DeclareVoidOption{myoptionthree}{Do something awesome}
\DeclareStringOption[bar]{foo}[bar]
\setkeys{hmm}{myoptionone,myoptiontwo}% This does work.
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
\endinput
```

The package `kvoptions` also loads `kvsetkeys` which provides the alternative `\kvsetkeys`. It is not used by default with `kvoptions` but you can enable it with the `setkeys` option in `\SetupKeyvalOptions`:

```
%% This is file `mypackage.sty'
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1997/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{
  family=hmm,
  prefix=hmm@,
  setkeys=\kvsetkeys
}
\DeclareVoidOption{myoptionone}{Do something}
\DeclareVoidOption{myoptiontwo}{Do some other things}
\DeclareVoidOption{myoptionthree}{Do something awesome}
\DeclareStringOption[bar]{foo}[bar]
\kvsetkeys{hmm}{myoptionone,myoptiontwo}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
\endinput
```

All details about `\kvsetkeys` can be found in the `kvsetkeys` manual but in this context the most important advantage of `\kvsetkeys` is being reentrant:

This means while `\kvsetkeys` is executed(e.g. during execution of the code given in `\DeclareVoidOption`), other commands using `\kvsetkeys`(perhaps internally) can still be used. This gives more freedom to the code in `\Declare...Option`.

Comment: Thank you! Heiko Oberdiek, the author of `kvoptions` stated [in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/MQ0hu33Kr7M) that `\kvsetkeys` is preferable over `\setkeys`. Would you please elaborate?